# How do I replace an uploaded level with a newer version?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

I tweaked one of my levels to prevent some cheese, but it wouldn't let me upload it again without deleting the previous level.  Unfortunately doing so lost all my previous likes and maker points associated with that level.  Was there any other way to 'refresh' the uploaded level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A newer version of a level counts as a new level

Clears, likes, and boos are all very related to the current state of a level. If I clear a level and the creator goes and adds 200 new spike blocks to it, it's not accurate to say I've cleared that level anymore (or that I'd still want to like it!).

If you've made some revisions to a level that you'd like to push out and you don't want to lose your maker points on the first version, simple save the new level as a 2.0 version and push that out alongside your original (keeping in mind that this still eats up another one of your limited upload slots).

Comment: I'm trying to do that. to keep a first clear I don't think it lets you upload a second version. (which is why I'm here)